# How to query contentresolver between two dates?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

How to query content resolver (`MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`) between two dates? I am trying following code but this is not working.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance()
Date date2 = c.getTime();
c.add(Calendar.YEAR,-1);
Date date1 = c.getTime();
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( 
                  MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                  projection, 
                  MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + ">=? and "+MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED +"<=?", 
                  new String[]{"" + date1,""+date2}, 
                  MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this [MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATE_ADDED) date time in long format.

for this you need to pass `long` data instead of `Date` object

Change your Query

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( 
              MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
              projection, 
              MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + ">=? and "+MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED +"<=?", 
              new String[]{"" + date1,""+date2}, 
              MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

into

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( 
              MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
              projection, 
              MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + ">=? and "+MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED +"<=?", 
              new String[]{"" + date1.getTtime()/1000,""+date2.getTime()/1000}, 
              MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Comment: Thanks, Working fine now. The problem is that date1.getTime() is giving time in milliseconds but DATE_ADDED is stored in seconds so I need to divide by 1000 to correct it.